# Handling a string from text file and continue with java program

Tags: java, string

The Text file:

```
9310,12,120,2,1
9333,12,120,2,1
PRINT
9533,5,45,0,0
8573,10,120,1,0
6343,6,18,170,0
PRINT
9311,12,120,2,1
3343,7,20,220,0
```

Code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
i mport java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;


public class FantasyPlayers {

    int player_ID;
    int total_score;

    public FantasyPlayers(int player, int total) {
        player_ID = player;
        total_score = total;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return player_ID + "," + total_score;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("Stats.txt");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String delims = "[,]";
        List<FantasyPlayers> Stats = new ArrayList<FantasyPlayers>();
        int a = 2;
        int b = 1;
        int c = 6;
        int d = -1;
        for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) 
        {
            String[] parsedData = line.split(delims);
            if (line != "PRINT")
            {
            int score = Integer.parseInt(parsedData[1])*a + Integer.parseInt(parsedData[2])*b +  Integer.parseInt(parsedData[3])*c + Integer.parseInt(parsedData[4])*d ;
            Stats.add(new FantasyPlayers(Integer.parseInt(parsedData[0]), score));
            }
            else
                continue;
        }
        br.close();

        System.out.println("Unordered");
        for (FantasyPlayers str : Stats) 
        {
                System.out.println(str);
        }
        Collections.sort(Stats, new Comparator<FantasyPlayers>()
            {
            public int compare(FantasyPlayers one, FantasyPlayers two)
            {
                if (one.total_score == two.total_score){
                    Integer playerOne = one.player_ID;
                    Integer playerTwo = two.player_ID;

                    return playerTwo.compareTo(playerOne);
                }
                Integer scoreOne = one.total_score;
                    Integer scoreTwo = two.total_score;

                return scoreTwo.compareTo(scoreOne);
                }
        });
        System.out.println("Ordered");
        for (FantasyPlayers str : Stats) 
        {
            System.out.println(str);
        }

     }

}
```

I Keep getting the Error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:1 at the `int score =` location.

My question is how do I handle the PRINT statements in the code...I'm able to do what I want with the data but I need the logic to do something when I read in the print statement. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You, my friend has fallen for the most common java mistakes....

try this

```
   if (!line.equalsIgnoreCase("PRINT"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change this line

```
String delims = "[,]";
```

to

```
String delims = ",";
```

and this line

```
line != "PRINT"
```

to

```
!line.trim().equals("PRINT")
```